# Error Connection Time Out after Certbot certificate installation

Tags: apache, openssl, certbot

I have installed Certbot certificate using `certbot --apache`. Installation was successful, now i'm unable to access my site over https.

When I hit command `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername` on server itself it gives `Connected (00000005)`

My [site](http://speedpainteramitverma.com) accessible over http. But unable to access over https.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The url you gave responds correctly in https (Amit Verma art) with a valid letsencrypt certificate.

Answer (score 6):

It's fixed now, actually issue was with AWS EC2 instance security group, port 443 wasn't enabled for inbound traffic.

Comment: OMG, I've wasted so many hours troubleshooting this. And the only reason was THIS. I'm so lucky I noticed your answer, who knows how many more hours I'd've wasted...

Comment: This was my issue as well, I think it's worth noting that this is fixed in the AWS UI and is not something that can be changed from the server's command line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sodium for the solution! Here are the actual steps to follow:

[1] Log in to AWS > EC2 Dashboard > Instances

[2] Select your instance. Under the instance summary information, select the "Security" tab. Click the "Security groups" link.

[3] Under Inbound rules > select "edit inbound rules" > select "add rule"

[4] Select: Type = Custom TCP >> Port range = 443 >> Source = custom >> 0.0.0.0/0

[5] Select "save rules" >> Refresh your site.

I spent well over 6 hours on this to realize it was an AWS issue, not an Apache server configuration issue.